# ASP.NET MVC and Spine.js Integration samples

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spine.js

Are there any sample websites/tutorials on integrating Spine.js with ASP.NET MVC? I have looked all over the web and I have only found ONE example from [Kazi Manzur](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/meet-spine-dot-js-my-framework-of-choice-for-client-side-mvc-part-1), and I was wondering if anybody else had more examples to share and talk about their experiences with this integration.

Comment: This sounds like an attempt to generate interest in this framework, rather than a specific programming question that others can help you with. It would be better to ask something specific about what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the intention. I'm new to JavaScript MVC frameworks and I'm coming from ASP.NET MVC background. I have been evaluating several frameworks and Spine seemed like the closest to my background. I just wanted to know if someone else has gone through the same or if I'm wrong recommend another one, and if they could share links to websites that could help me get started. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you...

http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/meet-spine-dot-js-my-framework-of-choice-for-client-side-mvc-part-1

http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/meet-spine-dot-js-my-framework-of-choice-for-client-side-mvc-part-2